# Multi-level merging of msbuild Directory.Build.props files

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have this structure:

```
\
  MySolution.sln
  Directory.Build.props     (1)
  \src
    Directory.Build.props   (2-src)
    \Project1
    \Project2
  \test
    Directory.Build.props   (2-test)
    \Project1Tests
    \Project2Tests
```

I have common properties for all projects (1), common properties for src projects (2-src), and common properties for test projects (2-test).

For (2-src) and (2-test) to import (1), according to [advice given at the repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2456), I added to each of them:

```
<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('Directory.Build.props'))" />
```

That doesn't work (I get an error that the import causes a circular dependency.). So I tried:

```
<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('Directory.Build.props', '../'))" />
```

Which also doesn't work for the same reason. But this does work:

```
<Import Project="../Directory.Build.props" />
```

I prefer to use the msbuild commands (which support a deeper directory structure), rather than a hardcoded value. Is that possible?

Comment: *rather than hardcoding* but isn't writing `GetPathOfFileAbove` essentially the same as writing `../`, i.e. in both cases you say - a.k.a. 'hardcode' -  where the file has to be found, namely one directory higher?

Comment: @stijn Fair point, I didn't express that well (updated that text). But still using msbuild commands seem better than using a hardcoded absolute path. Suppose that there is a deeper directory structure - using the commands would work, but my hardcoded value would fail.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can work around it by using the folder name of the current file (`$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)`):

```
  <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('Directory.Build.props', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\'))" />
```

This is required because relative paths are interpreted as relative to the project so just using `../` as the second parameter would always be "one up from the csproj" file regardless of the location of the file this statement is in.

Comment: What does that second argument actually mean? Is it the equivalent of "the directory above the current csproj directory"? How is that different to `../` - other of course than your way works and my way doesn't... I don't understand the syntax. :-)

Comment: Added an explanation to the answer.. relative paths handling are always relative to the project

Answer (score 8):

Worked for me, with a minor improvement:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ParentDirectoryBuildPropsPath>$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('Directory.Build.props', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\'))</ParentDirectoryBuildPropsPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<ImportGroup>
  <Import Project="$(ParentDirectoryBuildPropsPath)" />
</ImportGroup>
```

Condition accordingly, of course.

Comment: Nice approach, I was in a situation where the parent/outer `Directory.Build.props` may or may not exist so this allowed me to use `<Import Condition="$(ParentDirectoryBuildPropsPath) != ''" Project="$(ParentDirectoryBuildPropsPath)" />` to avoid a project load error when opening the solution.